# PHPExcel splitter by weight

Tags: split, phpexcel, large-data

I'm using PHPExcel library.

My excel file is very large to process and save to db.

Is there any way to split excel file by weight (ex: 100 MB) and then process each of split files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to split by specific byte sizes; but there are documented methods for reading a file in "chunks" - see section 4.3 entitled `"Reading Only Specific Columns and Rows from a File (Read Filters)"` of the PHPExcel User documentation for reading spreadsheet files for an explanation and example code.

You also don't mention if you are using cell caching to reduce memory usage; but that is described in section 4.2.1 entitled `Cell Caching` of the developer documentation, and also intended to reduce the memory footprint of large files